# python pandas linear regression curve

Tags: python, pandas

does anybody have a piece of code to calculate a rolling linear regression curve on a pandas dataframe?

i already have a function to calculate the slope for the entire dataframe, but I'm note sure how to apply / use it rolling:

```
def slope_intercept(x_val, y_val):
    x = np.array(x_val)
    y = np.array(y_val)
    m = ( ( (np.mean(x)*np.mean(y) ) - np.mean(x*y)) /
        ( ( np.mean(x)*np.mean(x)) - np.mean(x*x)))

    m = round(m,2)
    b=(np.mean(y)-np.mean(x)*m)
    b=round(b,2)
    return m,b

m,b=slope_intercept(df1.index.tolist(), df1['Close'].tolist())
df1['reg_line'] = [(m*x)+b for x in df1.index.tolist()]
```

thanks and cheers,
e.

Comment: "i already have a function to calculate the slope for the entire dataframe" - how do you do that now?

Comment: @AmiTavory i've extended the code above

Comment: anybody? thansk!